# DefaultIfEmpty issues with linq statement

Tags: c#, linq, ef-core-2.0

Can someone please explain to me what is going wrong here. I am using Linq to Sql to create a pretty nasty query.

The problem that I have is I need to left join on some of the tables 
(using `DefaultIfEmpty`) I need to return an specific object from the 
**`DefaultIfEmpty(new SomeObject(){...})`** so that i can do a join on it a bit later again.

My problem is that the DefaultIfEmpty always returns null. So i checked with some dummy data as a POC and it works

***Example***

I can't seem to find the link that I used to get the sample code below, I just altered it a bit to add an extra join to `OrderConfirmed` So when running it, it works as expected.

```
List<Book> bookList = new List<Book>
{
  new Book{BookID=1, BookNm="DevCurry.com Developer Tips"},
  new Book{BookID=2, BookNm=".NET and COM for Newbies"},
  new Book{BookID=3, BookNm="51 jQuery ASP.NET Recipes"},
  new Book{BookID=4, BookNm="Motivational Gurus"},
  new Book{BookID=5, BookNm="Spiritual Gurus"}
};

List<Order> bookOrders = new List<Order>
{
    new Order{OrderID=1, BookID=1, PaymentMode="Cheque"},
    new Order{OrderID=2, BookID=5, PaymentMode="Credit"},
    new Order{OrderID=3, BookID=1, PaymentMode="Cash"},
    new Order{OrderID=4, BookID=3, PaymentMode="Cheque"},
    new Order{OrderID=5, BookID=5, PaymentMode="Cheque"},
    new Order{OrderID=6, BookID=4, PaymentMode="Cash"}
};

List<OrderConfirmed> orderConfirmed = new List<OrderConfirmed>();


var orderForBooks = from bl in bookList
                    join ordr in bookOrders on bl.BookID equals ordr.BookID into a
                        from ordr in a.DefaultIfEmpty(new Order {BookID = -1, OrderID = 12, PaymentMode = "Cash Test" }) // return default value
                    join confirmed in orderConfirmed on ordr.OrderID equals confirmed.OrderID into c
                        from confirmed in c.DefaultIfEmpty(new OrderConfirmed() { OrderID = 12, Description = "Is this working"}) // no values in orderconfirmed so returning new object
                    select new
                               {
                                   bl,
                                   ordr,
                                   confirmed
                    };
```

So knowing that what i am trying todo should work, in my actual code the `DefaultIfEmpty` is always null. Am i right in saying that this should work?
Maybe something to note that i am using `EFCORE`

```
var formData = 
 await (from ccf in this.context.Set<BureauCountryCustomForm>()
          join ccfa in this.context.Set<EmployeeCustomFormAttributeHeader>() on ccf.BureauCountryFormId equals ccfa.BureauCountryFormId into ccfaJoin
          from ccfa in ccfaJoin.DefaultIfEmpty(new EmployeeCustomFormAttributeHeader()
                                                   {
                                                       HeaderId = -1,
                                                       BureauCountryFormId = 3,
                                                       CompanyFormId = -1,
                                                       EmployeeId = 1
                                                   })
          join cca in this.context.Set<BureauCountryCustomFormAttribute>() on ccf.BureauCountryFormId equals cca.BureauCountryFormId
          join edv in this.context.Set<EmployeeCustomFormValue>() on
              new { AttributeId = (int?)cca.BureauCountryFormAttributeId, HeaderId = (int?)ccfa.HeaderId } equals
              new { AttributeId = (int?)edv.FormAttributeId, HeaderId = (int?)edv.HeaderId } into edvJoin
          from edv in edvJoin.DefaultIfEmpty(new EmployeeCustomFormValue()
                                                 {
                                                     HeaderId = -1,
                                                     FormAttributeId = -1
                                                 })
          where ccf.CountryId == countryId && ccf.EmployeeLevel == true && ccfa.EmployeeId == employeeId
          select new { ccf, ccfa, cca, edv }).GroupBy(g => new { g.ccf.BureauCountryFormId, g.ccfa.HeaderId })
.Select(
_ => new CustomFormData
{
    Keys = new[] { _.Key.BureauCountryFormId, _.Key.HeaderId },
    FormName = _.First().ccf.FormName,
    EffectiveDate = _.First().ccfa.EffectiveDate,
    FormDataFields = _.Select(
                 f => new CustomFormDataField
                 {
                     AttributeId = f.cca.BureauCountryFormAttributeId,
                     FieldLabel = f.cca.FieldLabel,
                     IsMandatory = f.cca.IsMandatory,
                     FieldValue = f.edv.FieldValue,
                     ControlTypeId = (long)f.cca.ControlTypeId,
                     DropdownValues = f.cca.DropdownValues,
                     Order = f.cca.AttOrderNo,
                     ValidationRule = f.cca.ValidationRule,
                     ValidationExpression = f.cca.ValidationExpression
                 }).ToList()
}).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: I doubt anyone is going to answer your question as is Please Provide [MCVE] this provides too much detail and abstracts your issue, and to be honest your code should be refactored so other developers on your team won't have a hard time reading this

Comment: Also, as a side note now that c# defines the `_` operator you should never use it as a variable name unless you don't intend to use it, this could also be the reason why you don't get result but I don't know because I didn't bother to read your full query

Comment: What database provider are you using?

Comment: @netmage i am using MSSql

Comment: @jonny, i realized its a lot but honestly i was not sure how to explain the actual problem. That is way i did the first example as a dumb down version.

Comment: And yes i do agree it needs a refactor but will only be doing it in the end

Comment: @Jonny 5 i will try and update it anyways. Guess i can take out the properties that i dont need in ths example

Comment: Perhaps reduce it to one `join` with `DefaultIfEmpty(`...`)` and see if it works, and then post that code?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in:

```
from ccfa in ccfaJoin.DefaultIfEmpty(new EmployeeCustomFormAttributeHeader())
```

Such a query construction should be used only with collections like db sets or queries not DefaultIfEmpty which however is IEnumerable but EF Core treats it as single value (which really in sql query result is null if there is no match) wherever it is used.

You should change it to:

```
let ccfa = ccfaJoin.DefaultIfEmpty(new EmployeeCustomFormAttributeHeader())
```

And it should work as expected.

Comment: That isn't correct for [EF Core](https://weblogs.asp.net/dixin/entity-framework-core-and-linq-to-entities-4-query-methods)

Comment: @arekzyla will try that as soon as i get to work. However i did try something similar. Will let you know.

Comment: even though using the "let" keyword kind of worked it did not really work with the rest of the statement. I have decided to actually just simplify the statement. +1 for help